# "Operation could destabilize the runtime" when calling dynamic method

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I am trying to right a Func that I can use to access the get method of a property, but have hit a stumbling block.

The dynamic method below is created fine, however when it is invoked I get the following error.

VerificationException, Operation could destabilize the runtime.

I have checked that the il code emits a valid function by writing it to a class rather than a dynamic method and all would appear to be fine.

I'm guessing it has to do with some typing issue but I'm not sure where, so any help is appreciated.

Example class

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public string Property{get;set;}
}
```

Dynamic method creation

```
var getMethods = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty,
                                   typeof(string),
                                   new Type[] {typeof(object) });
var ilGet = getMethods.GetILGenerator();
var falseGetLabel = ilGet.DefineLabel();

ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, typeof(DemoClass));
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, falseGetLabel);
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, typeof(DemoClass));
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(DemoClass).GetProperty("Property").GetMethod);
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
ilGet.MarkLabel(falseGetLabel);
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj,
           typeof(InvalidOperationException).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
ilGet.Emit(OpCodes.Throw);

var f = (Func<object,string>)getMethods.CreateDelegate(
                                           typeof(Func<object,string>));

var x = new DemoClass{Property = "9"};

Console.WriteLine(f(x)); <--- fails here
```

Comment: I'm not CIL-literate, but could you perhaps use expressions to generate a dynamic method? It is much safer and easier to use, and you probably won't encounter verification issues with it.

Comment: It is not close to correct IL, too many mistakes to list.  Always write this code in C# first and use ildasm.exe to look at the generated IL so you'll have a decent starting point.

Comment: @HansPassant as I stated in my question wehn I emit the above IL through a type builder to a method it not only creates the type but allows me to use the method just fine. I have also compared it to output from Linqpad and checked it in ILdasm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `OpCodes.Ldarg_0` instead of `OpCodes.Ldarg_1` to get first method argument.

Comment: I retyped and checked my IL against linqpad generated code and it still wanted me to use arg1 instead of arg0. Either way Arg0 did the trick, thanks

Comment: @SCB For instance methods, argument 0 is `this`, so the first normal argument is 1. But for static methods (like the one you're creating using `DynamicMethod`), there is no `this`, so first argument is number 0.

Comment: @svick thanks, makes sense and I should have probably picked that it up earlier.